# Does Mind Blank also protect your gear?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, divination

Does Mind Blank protect magic items or even normal gear that is on the Mind Blanked target from divination spells (including but not limited to Detect Magic, Locate Object, etc.)?

Another player and I aren't currently in agreement on this. I think Mind Blank will also protect my stuff but he is telling me that Nondetection is what I should be using, and his reason for that is a bit of text at the end of Nondetection that isn't in the Mind Blank spell:

> If cast on a creature, nondetection wards the creature’s gear as well as the creature itself.

I have not brought this question to the GM yet because he is in blackout mode studying for his exams and can't be reached yet.

If the majority answer is "Yes it protects your gear as well" could you  put the reasoning why in the answer as well? So when the GM is free I can bring it to him and the other player before the game so it doesn't devolve into a debate at the table.

Comment: Now to wait for the  massive edit to my question that always happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it also protects your gear

All protective spells, unless stated otherwise, extend to your equipment, as they are part of *"you*". Just like attack spells will not any of your gear unless you critically fail a saving thrown or the spell says otherwise.

[Mind Blank](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mind-blank/) is no exception. It says:

> **The subject** is protected from all devices and spells that gather information about **the target** through divination magic (such as detect evil, locate creature, scry, and see invisible). This spell also grants a +8 resistance bonus on saving throws against all mind-affecting spells and effects. Mind blank even foils limited wish, miracle, and wish spells when they are used in such a way as to gain information about **the target**. In the case of scrying that scans an area **the creature** is in, such as arcane eye, the spell works but **the creature** simply isn’t detected. Scrying attempts that are targeted specifically at **the subject** do not work at all.

As you can see, there are no exceptions here about their equipment, and as such, it follows the general rules for [targeting attended gear](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw).

The difference from [Nondetection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/nondetection/) is that it can specifically target a piece of equipment, which may or may not be carried, and it also has a much lower spell level (2nd). So, depending on what your objective really is, such as hide that you are carrying something or simply protect yourself from scrying, *Nondetection* will be used in different ways. While *Mind Blank* is *catch-all*  *"F--- off, divination spells"*.

Note that this is a commonly asked question at paizo messageboards, and the community agrees that it should also protect your gear, as seen [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2n6eq?Does-mind-blank-protect-your-gear#1), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2tnkk?Arcane-Sight-and-Mind-Blank#2), and [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rof4?Does-mind-blank-protect-your-gear-as-well#1) too.

Answer (score 2):

**Probably yes...**

...but it is not explicitly stated in the wording.  There are two lines of reasoning to consider here.

Firstly, Mind Blank is an 8th level spell that can foil even Wish, Limited Wish and Miracle when used to try to detect the creature.  Let us consider the case of Aldo the All-Powerful, a 15th level wizard who has cast Invisibility and Mind Blank on himself.  Numpty the Newbie is a 3rd level wizard who has cast See Invisibility.  If Mind Blank is interpreted as not protecting Aldo's possessions, it would mean that Aldo is *only* protected from detection by Numpty if he is completely naked and carrying no equipment, otherwise his clothing and possessions can be easily seen using a 2nd level spell (which will immediately give away Aldo's location).  This is a ludicrous result for an 8th level spell when compared to Nondetection, which is only a 4th level spell.  On this basis alone, as a GM I would rule that Mind Blank also includes carried items.

Secondly, it is worth comparing the 3.5 version of Mind Blank with the Pathfinder version.  The 3.5 version did not include equipment because its primary purpose was to protect against "all devices and spells that detect, influence or read emotions or thoughts."  While there were secondary effects protecting against scrying, the main purpose of the spell was complete immunity to mind-influencing effects, rather than "just" a +8 bonus on saving throws against them.  Obviously, this was irrelevant to equipment unless an intelligent item was being carried.  My *assumption* is that when the spell was adjusted in purpose for Pathfinder to protect against all detection it was an oversight that carried equipment was not included.  (I have no supporting evidence for this.)

I suggest that you discuss this further with your fellow player and try to agree on a common position before jointly approaching your GM (once he is finished cramming).  Whichever way the eventual discussion goes, the lack of explicit wording means that it will come down to GM fiat.

Comment: That was the reasoning i was coming to as well.
Thank you